# Help with converting scheme

Tags: resistors, schematics

I have this scheme and I can't make it look normal in order to count total resistancce
[image]

Comment: Just start by reducing the number of resistors and it will soon resolve itself.

Comment: *Starting hint*   - look at r2,r3 and r5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it doesn't look like you want us to solve it for you which is the reason I am helping. If you had wanted it solved for you, you would have provided values.
my guess is perhaps you just want to look at the circuit in a different layout, in which case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCnEsV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

looking at it this way may be what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, I got same thing but I can't understand what to do next? On previous answer I commented that I dont understand - this is parallel scheme with two or three lines?

Comment: As Lorenzo Donati said, how are r2, r3, and r5 connected? what does this connection mean about their resistances? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits

Comment: When solving circuits like this, (as with most things in electrical engineering/programming) don't try to swallow the whole thing at once. Look at what CAN be simplified, take care of the simplification. Usually that leads to another part that can be simplified, and so on.

Comment: I understand that they are in one line and their total R = r2+r3+r5, my question is - can we make it look like [here](http://croper.ru/images/201610139kfMpIYuOIKEqJi9_5qCho_large.jpeg?86614) ?

Comment: yes, both of the schematics you are showing us are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an homework question. We don't fully answer homework questions that show no effort in finding a solution. We provide hints, instead.

Here are some:

How are R2, R3 and R5 connected?

How is R6 connected with respect to the previous hint? Does the circuit simplify a bit?

If you simplified the circuit as per the hints above, how is R1 connected now? Does it simplify further?

And then R4...

Comment: Small addition - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits :)

Comment: yes, I see that R2, R3 and R5 are inline and I tried to convert this scheme and this what I got 
[link](http://croper.ru/images/20161013pgkMfIFOufIZi8D7_EJ4d4_large.jpeg)

But I cant understand what to do that line on the right, close to point b. This scheme must be parallel with 3 lines or with 2?

Comment: @Leopik handle that in steps. Substitute those three resistors with its equivalent resistance. Then look at the circuit and see what you can do next with *that* equivalent resistance and R6.